I am yielding to an ERB file, but it is rendering in plain text and not HTML. Why?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ranked!</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #f4f4f9;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 3em;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
    .banner {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      color: #777;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .logout-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      right: 20px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      background-color: #f44336;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .logout-button:hover {
      background-color: #e53935;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Welcome to Ranked!</h1>
  <div class="banner">Share your passions</div>

  <!-- Logout button -->
  <form action="/logout" method="post">
    <button class="logout-button" type="submit">Logout</button>
  </form>
  <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>

This is my layout.erb file and this is the very simple file I am trying to yield to.
<div class="sub-banner">Your Ranks</div>


<form action="/create_rank" method="get">
  <button class="create-button" type="submit">Create New Rank</button>
</form>

When it renders however, it reads the second file in plain text and not HTML as intended. This is a sinatra based app.
I have tried running on multiple environments/machines, changing the content of the files, creating new files, and nothing helps.
I should add that this is the route in my controller.
get "/myranks" do
  erb :myranks, layout: :layout
end


You did not specify if the "file I am trying to yield to" is called myranks.erb nor do I understand what you mean "it reads the second file in plain text and not HTML as intended".

Are you using erubi? If so, try <%== yield %> (double ==) to disable escaping.
